# function takes a number and return a infinite list of Multiples of the number

Tags: haskell

so I wrote a function that takes a number and return a infinite list of  Multiples of the number,

```
multiples :: Integer -> [Integer]
multiples x = [ y*x | y <- [1..]]
```

now if I wrote

```
multiples :: (Num a) => a -> [a]
```

it shows error, I don't know when to use Typeclasses and when not

Comment: "It shows an error" is not helpful. For future problems, report the exact error. We can teach you how to understand ghc error messages so you can learn to solve the problem.

Answer (score 5):

`Num a` isn't sufficient; `a` must also have an `Enum` constraint so that you can use `[1..]`.

```
multiples :: (Num a, Enum a) => a -> [a]
```

Your first definition works because both `Num Integer` and `Enum Integer` exist.

If you didn't want to rely on the `Enum` constraint, you could change your definition to something like

```
multiples x = iterate (+x) x
```

or use a function internally that fixes a type with an `Enum` instance:

```
multiples x = [fromInteger n * x | n <- [1..]]
```

`[1..]` by itself produces a `(Enum a) => [a]` value, but the use of `fromInteger :: Num a => Integer -> a` fixes the type of `[1..]` to `[Integer]`.

Comment: You dropped the `a` in `Enum a`. Also, the two versions have different behavior, which can be seen with a) finite `Num`eric types (it always gives an infinite list, which may be desirable) and b) floating point (it accrues unnecessary rounding error and also gets stuck after too many iterations). Perhaps note those. Also, your version is very slow: I tried to test its failure for floating point (I believe it'll give `1 == multiples (1 / 16777216 :: Float) !! (16777216 + 2)` as `True`) but I couldn't reach it. `multiples x = [fromInteger n * x | n <- [1..]]` is the same idea but IMO better.

Comment: True; those would all be good reasons to rely on the `Enum` constraint :)

Comment: ? `multiples x = [fromInteger n * x | n <- [1..]]` fixes both the speed and floating point problem but doesn't rely on a visible `Enum` constraint. The infinite/finite thing remains, yes.

Comment: Also, by "finite", I assume you mean something like `multiples 3 :: [Z4] == [0, 3, 2, 1]` if dealing with multiplication mod 4, rather than `[0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, 2, 1, 0, 3, ...]`?

Comment: Yes. I suppose which one we want in that case depends on use case.

Comment: Ah, ok, so using `fromInteger` fixes the type of `n` to `Integer`, rather than an arbitrary `Enum` type.

Comment: `multiples x = x : map (+ x) (multiples x)` probably has a quadratic slowdown. `iterate (+ x) x` is better.

Comment: Not sure why I didn't use `iterate` in the first place.